# Javascript: Get body html in one row string. How to remove linebreaks?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have html

```
<span style="font-family: tahoma, arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 10pt;">One
two:</span>
```

I need to receive html in one row string.

```
a = $("body").clone().find("script").remove().end().html();
a = a.replace("\r\n", "zzz");
a = a.replace("\n", "zzz");
console.log(a);
```

But it's not working. I get all the same.

```
<span style="font-family: tahoma, arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 10pt;">One
two:</span>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace all new line characters with regex and global flag:

```
a.replace(/\r?\n/g, ' ');
```

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/miqef/1/edit)

Comment: Thank you. I have one more question depend on this. But I don't know can I ask it in comments, so I created [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22561028/javascript-regexp-with-linebreaks)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that string.replace, only removes the first occurence of the string you define, you need to use regex with the `global` option instead:

```
a = $("body").clone().find("script").remove().end().html();
a = a.replace(/\r\n/g, " ");
a = a.replace(/\n/g, " ");
console.log(a);
```

[`VisioN`'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22558754/1044856) is better though, as it takes both scenarios into account in one regex, making it alot faster.