# JavaScript RegExp with linebreaks

Tags: javascript

I need to find (and replace in future) a string with linebreaks on a HTML page (without modifying any other parts). My code: http://jsbin.com/jatipize/1/edit.

Where's the bug?

Comment: your jsbin is missing jquery .... and what are you doing with that regexp????

Comment: you need to be more specific about what you are wanting to find and replace. e.g. show a "before" and "after", explain which part is "a string" etc..

Comment: @rafaelcastrocouto no, jq in the head. i want to find some string in html body.

Comment: @CrayonViolent I want to find some string (which can contain linebreaks) and replace it for another string. My working example only find string and I have trouble with it.

Comment: you gotta work on that english dude ... and remember that html parser will remove those line breaks `\n` and respect only `<br>`, unless you got a `pre` white-space value

Comment: @rafaelcastrocouto but it is working http://jsbin.com/fotejado/1/edit

Comment: "some string" and "another string" is not specific enough. Unless you explain *exactly* what those are, all we can give you is generic replace operation, eg.  `string=string.replace(/\n|\r/g,'');` But how do you get the `string` value in the first place? I don't know, because you haven't explained it

Comment: @CrayonViolent String defined by user, for example. String can be various.

Comment: well okay, then it sounds like i gave you an answer then. You figure out how to get the content into `string` and there's how you remove the line breaks, then put the `string` back into content

Comment: @CrayonViolent Ok, I change my question. I have [new example](http://jsbin.com/vazihepe/1/edit). Why it's working with "a" variable and not working with "b" variable?

Comment: @CrayonViolent If I remove linebreaks in content and put back it - another parts of page can me modified too.

Comment: Please put the code in the question directly (to avoid link rot), along with a description of what you expect to see, and what you actually see.

Comment: There is no bug ... if you want variable "b" to work you must test it against `document.body.textContent`

Comment: @rafaelcastrocouto textContent not contains html tags, isn't it?

Comment: no it does not ... just content in there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your HTML is incorrectly formatted. You have an ending

tag without a beginning one. The console logs this for a:

```
<strong><span style="font-family: tahoma, arial, helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 10pt;">One
two:</span></strong><p></p>
```

Your RegEx ends in:

```
</strong></p>
```

which doesn't match.

Putting a beginning <p> outside of strong works (or just take out the </p> at the end of your regex).

**Edit:**

You also have to remove the newline stuff around the font:

```
sans-serif;\r?\nfont-size
```

doesn't match the above text.